# Transparent navbar without bootstrap https://jsfiddle.net/dtxxxmnt/

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the navbar transparent then have opacity when you scroll down. I know there are other questions like this, but they are using bootstrap. I am not using bootstrap.

Edit: I added code. (in title)

Comment: Add some code for see what you have tried or not or just to tell you what is wrong..

Comment: I added code. Its in the title because it said i could not add it to the body.

Comment: thanks, i edit my answer with a fix for your code.

Answer (score 1):

there is a javascript event that you can listen to the scroll:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll

When the callback is called you can set the opacity to a different amount.
You can also add a css transition to make the opacity change smoother.

The scroll event have a nasty side-effect and that is that scrolling can be clunky. To prevent that you can debounce or throttle it. A article about that: https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls

updated with example. You used the wrong scroll check. Use `window.pageYOffset`. Also the selector to get the navbar did not work. Don't know why but with querySelector it works :). Also I added the white background to the css as a default so it will be white when you load the page.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  transbar();
};

function transbar() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 50) {
    document.querySelector("#navbar").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#navbar").style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
}
```

```css
.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
  display: none;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #ffaa00;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #ffaa00;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
}

.navbar:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.navbar ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar ul li {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: #ffaa00;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

#active {
  color: #ffaa00;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navbar" id="navbar">
    <nav>
      <div id="logo">Your Logo here</div>

      <label for="drop" class="toggle">&#9776;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="Index.html" id="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia itaque rem, ea sit quos. Inventore modi sed, provident laborum nobis asperiores repellat esse voluptatum expedita, ea culpa sequi id magnam? 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the code there is little we can do to fix. But I can offer you a general style for said navbar for you to upgrade or modify if you have stuck with where to go:

```
 .myNavbar{
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

You wanna go with background color transparency instead using opacity for element. This took me a half hour to do the 1st time couple a years ago, cause I was stupid and were adjusting the text color to look like before I put opacity to the navbar.

Ofc, for different colors you need to edit `rgba` values. Here is what they mean:

> RGBA color values are an extension of RGB color values with an alpha
>   channel - which specifies the opacity for a color.
>
> An RGBA color value is specified with: rgba(red, green, blue, alpha).
>   The alpha parameter is a number between 0.0 (fully transparent) and
>   1.0 (fully opaque).